# Complicated slicing operation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am stuck with slicing operation on Tensorflow. What I want to do is like this in Numpy,

```
>>> a = np.arange(24).reshape((4,6))
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
>>> print(a[[2,3],[0,1]])
array([12, 19])
```

However in Tensorflow,

```
>>> a = tf.Variable(np.arange(24).reshape((4,6)))
>>> with tf.Session() as sess:
...  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
...  print(sess.run(a[[2,3],[0,1]]))
```

I got an error saying `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`. Is there any way to perform this slicing in Tensorflow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way. But I've reorganized the indices(`[2,0],[3,1]`).

```
a = tf.Variable(np.arange(24).reshape((4, 6)))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(tf.gather_nd(a, [[2,0],[3,1]])))
```

Output is

> [12 19]